# Should field labels be nouns or verbs?

Tags: forms, user-behavior, copywriting, labels, wording

On a web form should field labels be nouns or verbs? This issue arose from two fields on an account request form that currently read:

- Temporary Password
- Re-Enter Temporary Password

There is debate as to whether a verb should **ever** sneak in. From general observation I believe nouns are more frequently used - especially for sign-up forms - but I do know that breaking a pattern can draw attention to the item.

So, nouns or verbs (or both)? Links to studies would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, JohnGB. I am aware of the concept of acceptance, but I find that multiple responses tend to contain important information. Now if you gave me the option to accept multiple answers... :)

Comment: Multiple options are available for dinner every night, each with their own benefits, but you still gotta choose one. Just sayin... :)

Comment: Yeah - I've not thought about it before. You are both right - I'm denying points which isn't fair. I'll reform, I promise.

Answer (score 7):

Always **break the rules when it makes sense**.

**Clarity** is an important enough reason to break every other UX rule.

Your **labels are clear**, even if they don't follow the standard convention of a noun for a label and a verb for a call to action.  If you were to try use a noun for the label it would be "Re-entered temporary password", or "temporary password again" - neither of which is a better solution.

Comment: Agreed. I think so long as there is a clear argument/justification then it makes the decision easier. Thanks.

Comment: @GaryFranceschini: It's more about it being the best option.  You can justify almost anything, so don't use that as the criterion.

Comment: There's a lot to be said about determining "the best option", but I take your point.

Answer (score 4):

Prompts are very different from placeholders.  For prompts, being clear and concise wins every time.  This is totally okay:

**Username**
--Field--

**Password**
--Field--

**Confirm Password**
--Field--

However, placeholders are often better in practice (think iPhone text fields).  If you're using a placeholder, make the placeholder the same *type* as what the user will actually fill in.

If it's an address field, use "333 Main Street".

If it's a user name use "John Doe", etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
Temporary password:  __________________________
         and again:  __________________________
```

Comment: Assaf, I think natural language - such as your example - has it's place, but I was more concerned with the concept of noun vs. verb as other posters have addressed.